# check if user logged in before template loads, execute 2 different actions depending user is logged in

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm learnign angular.js and ui-router. So I'm triying to understand: 
1. How to do two different actions in one state depending user is logged in or no.
2. In several sates redirect to home pageif user is Not Logged in

Here is example: 
There is a servise "Atuhentication" that countains authentiated user. But I can't load it to module.config() it hrows an error.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        // if user is logged in go to state "chat"
        // else go to state "welcome"
    })
    .state('chat', function(){
        // if user is not logged in redirect to home page
    })
```

I tried to make it in state's controllers, but it is dirty way, because it loads template & controller and then check if user logged in and redirects if not.

So dear friends, please show the right direction to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always hook & prevent the state change using `$stateChangeStart` event which is being broadcasted when a state is changed. You can add this event listener either in any top level controller which is available through out the app (like a controller added to `body` tag) or you can add this event listener code in any service using `$rootScope` like below:

```
var protectedStates = ['home', 'chat'];

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
     // See if state being transitioned needs to be access checked
     if (protectedStates.indexOf(toState.name) > -1) {
         if (!userLoggedIn) {
              // Prevent the current state from being changed
              event.preventDefault();
              $state.go('home');       // go to home page or login page.
         }
     }
});
```

For more reference: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: Wouldn't it be `protectedStates.indexOf(toState)`?